# JPA: persist self relationship when class uses EmbeddedId

Tags: java, jpa

I've this self relationship

```
    public class Estoria implements Serializable {

      @EmbeddedId 
      protected EstoriaPK estoriaPK; 

      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "id_estoria", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable = false, insertable = false, nullable = true)
                  ,@JoinColumn(name = "id_projeto" , referencedColumnName = "id_projeto" ,     insertable = false, updatable = false)})
      private Estoria subtask;

      @OneToMany(mappedBy = "subtask",cascade = CascadeType.ALL) 
      private Collection<Estoria> subtasks; 
    }
```

and my Ids

```
    @Embeddable 
    public class EstoriaPK implements Serializable {

     @Basic(optional = false)
      @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
      private int id;
      @Basic(optional = false)
      @NotNull
      @Column(name = "id_projeto", unique = true, nullable = false)
      private int idProjeto;

      // GETTRs and SETTERs
    }
```

And I try to persist using cascade

```
        public void persistSubtask(int idEstoria,Estoria subtask) {
        try {
            estoria = this.entityManager.createNamedQuery("Estoria.findById",Estoria.class)
                                .setParameter("id", idEstoria)
                                .getSingleResult();

            subtask.setEstoriaPK(new EstoriaPK(0,estoria.getProjeto().getId())); 
            subtask.setSubtask(estoria);
            this.entityManager.persist(subtask);  


        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new NoPersistException("falha ao persistir subtask");
        } 
    }
```

This is not working because my foreing-key wasn't persisted, are there some annotation mistakes?

If I try to persist a collection doesn't work fine because their father reference doesn't persist, are there any other annotation problem that I need to fix?

Comment: if I understand what you're trying to achieve, isn't it because of the insertable = false, updatable = false ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be the

```
insertable = false, updatable = false
```

Comment: So the error is that JPA can't insert the appropriate mapping for the subtask because of this? I understand that removing this solved the OP's problem, but a little more context won't hurt other users finding this answer later on.